# Fix broken html element in list

Tags: python, string, list, replace, find

I got this list looking something like this

```
words = ['how', 'much', 'is</b>', 'the', 'fish</b>', 'no', 'really']
```

I would like to add `<b>` to the beginning of every string ending with `</b>`, without losing the word sequence.

```
words = ['how', 'much', '<b>is</b>', 'the', '<b>fish</b>', 'no', 'really']
```

I've elaborated a lot by now so a little help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> words = ['how', 'much', 'is</b>', 'the', 'fish</b>', 'no', 'really']
>>> words = ['<b>'+i if i.endswith('</b>') else i for i in words]
>>> words
['how', 'much', '<b>is</b>', 'the', '<b>fish</b>', 'no', 'really']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be more generic and work for all tags you can do something like this:

```
import re

def change_word(word):
    m = re.search(r'^.*</(.*)>$', word)
    return "<{0}>{1}".format(m.group(1),word)

words = ['how', 'much', 'is</b>', 'the', 'fish</b>', 'no', 'really</div>']      
words = [change_word(i) if re.match(r'^.*</(.*)>$', i) else i for i in words]
print words
```

Result:

```
 ['how', 'much', '<b>is</b>', 'the', '<b>fish</b>', 'no', '<div>really</div>']
```